# Why won't Settings Open 22.04

Tags: crash, settings, system-settings

Tried to fresh reinstall because of grub issues and it not recognizing windows yadda yadda yadda. And now, Settings just doesn't open. It tries to. Then it just silently crashes.

https://streamable.com/4r7s8x

Desktop recording of the process.

I assume I just need to totally uninstall Ubuntu to resolve that?

I tried "apt purge gnome-control-center" "apt install gnome-control-center" from googling other solutions, that did nothing.

Comment: Can you add the output of `gnome-control-center -v`?

Comment: Crashes due to software (not hardware) invariably leave lots of information in the logs -- that's what the logs are for. Find your logs, locate the section full of information about your crash, and add that relevant section to your Question above.

Comment: Nope, because I reinstalled the whole system again. Initially a restart ended up fixing it. But then another error came up and needed to reinstall the entire OS again.

Comment: I had the same issue and did as @EmreTalha said: "
(gnome-control-center:37766): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 20:54:20.324: Unable to initialize Clutter: Initialisierung des Clutter-Backends nicht möglich: Keine Treiber verfügbar." Then segfault.

Comment: @Semo you should ask another question for your problem. This one is abandoned and probably won't get a working answer.